# Confusion about the Total Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I just started multivariable calculus a little while ago and I'm confused about the concept of a total derivative of some function $z = z(x, y)$. I was taught that $dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot dy$, and my understanding is that $dz$ represents an infinitesimal rate of change in $z$, and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ is the rate of change of $z$ w.r.t. $x$ while $y$ remains constant. So if $dz$ is the rate of change of $z$ and $z$ relies on two variables, shouldn't the rate of change be given by a vector $<\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}>$? Why is it simply the sum of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the total derivative is saying is that we should have

$$f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y) \approx f(x,y)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Delta x +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Delta y$$

We call the function $df\big|_{(x,y)}: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$
df\big|_{(x,y)}\left( \begin{bmatrix} \Delta x \\ \Delta y\end{bmatrix}\right) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Delta x +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Delta y
$$

The total derivative of $f$ at $(x,y)$.  This is a linear map, whose matrix with respect to the standard basis is

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix}
$$

so sometimes we also call this matrix the total derivative (sometimes the "jacobian matrix of $f$").

In general the total derivative of a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ will be a different linear function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ at each point of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  The total derivative is recorded by the $m \times n$ matrix of partial derivatives.

Comment: Alright, I think I'm starting to understand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3002473  I should also note that according to this convention for $df$, $dx$ is really just the linear map $\langle a,b \rangle \mapsto a$, similarly $dy$ is the map $\langle a,b \rangle \mapsto b$.  So we can literally write: $$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy$$ Where this is understood as an equality of functions.

Comment: your last remark: won’t it be a $ m$ x $n$ matrix? Since $f$ is determined by $m$ component functions (of $n$ variables)?

Comment: @Jess you are right.  I always goof on whether $n \times m$ should mean $n$ rows or $n$ columns.  The standard convention is backward to me because you always say the domain of a function first.