# total derivative with respect to x

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to learn multi-variable calculus. I understand the meaning of partial derivative. But I am not getting the  meaning of $$\dfrac{df(x,y)}{dx}$$. Please explain.

Comment: You mean what that stands for, or why we use that particular notation?

Comment: Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911176/confusion-about-the-total-derivative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's compare the partial and total derivatives.

The partial derivative $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}$ is the value you get by differentiating $f$ with respect to $x$ while holding $y$ constant (evaluated at the point $(x,y,f(x,y))$).

But there's nothing to stop $y$ from *also* having some dependence on $x$.  So when you hold $y$ constant you're potentially removing some of the effect of differentiating with respect to $x$.  So instead we can take the *total* derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ via the multivariable chain rule:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dx}$$

This tells us *exactly* (or as exactly as first derivatives can) how some small change in $x$ is going to change the value of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

It implies implicit differentiation it simply means derivative of function whch has both $y,x$ terms wrt to $x$ .